# C language: why do these two printf statements print different things

Tags: c, pointers, struct, printf, return-value

```
#include <stdio.h>
typedef struct {
    int data;
    char * string;
}Node;

Node * init(){
    Node node;
    node.data = 5;
    node.string = "hello";
    Node * point = &node;
    return point;
}
int main() {
    Node * test = init();
    printf("%d\n", test->data);
    printf("%d", test->data);   
}
```

Why do the last two printf statements produce different results. I suspect is has something to do with how I assigned my test pointer, but I don't know how to fix it.

Answer (score 3):

In your case, `node` is a variable local to the function `init()` and yet, you return the address of this. So, once the function is returned, there's no existence of `node` anymore.

After the function returns accessing the return value is accessing invalid memory which causes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

You can, however, return the structure variable itself, not a pointer to it and collect the return value in the caller in another variable, it'll work out.

Comment: @weijazhou Please re-read the last paragraph in the answer, just updated it. :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your code has undefined behavior on account of returning a pointer to a function local object. But it seems your approach is misguided to begin with. Your init function is supposed to initialize a structure with a proper initial value, there's no need to return a pointer to do this. You have three options:

1. Return by value, like another answer suggested.
2. Pass the address of a structure for the function to initialize. This frees up the return value, so you can signal success or failure:

   ```
   bool init(Node *node) { // must include stdbool.h
       if(!node)
         return false;

       node->data = 5;
       node->string = "hello";
       return true;
   }

   //...

   Node test;
   if(!init(&test)) {
     //failed to initialize, handle the error 
   }
   ```
3. Forgo the function entirely and supply a macro that stands for the nodes initial value:

   ```
   #define NODE_INIT_VAL { \
     .data = 5, .string = "hello", \
   }
   ```

   This allows you to simply write `Node test = NODE_INIT_VAL;`. It's also how you'd prefer to initialize any objects with static storage duration.

Answer (score 0):

node is defined as local variable in the function `init()` so it's memory is freed after the function returns.

You should either define node as global variable (I don't like globals :-)) or allocate memory by calling [malloc](https://linux.die.net/man/3/malloc).

```
node = malloc(sizeof(Node));
```

Don't forget to free the memory if you no longer need node.

Answer (score 0):

Update init() to return struct:

```
    Node init(){
    Node node;
    node.data = 5;
    node.string = "hello";
    return node;
}
```

then access it like the following :

```
Node testNode = init();
printf("%d\n", testNode.data);
printf("%d", testNode.data);
```

Or if you want to use pointer like this :

```
Node testNode = init();
Node* pointerToNode = &testNode;
printf("%d\n", pointerToNode->data);
printf("%d", pointerToNode->data);
```

And the reason for this is as @Sourav answered that the data will be no longer valid.

Hope this is useful.